# javascript on hover is not working on ajax load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using following code for on hover.But this code does not work on ajaxload.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.products-grid .item').hover(function(){ 
        jQuery(this).find('.pro-review').animate({bottom:'0'}, 200);
        jQuery(this).find('.pro-view').show();
    }, function(){  
        jQuery(this).find('.pro-review').stop(true,true).animate({bottom:'-37'}, 200);
        jQuery(this).find('.pro-view').hide();
    });
)};
</script>
```

I found alternate for this like following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).on("hover",".products-grid .item", function () {
            jQuery(this).find('.pro-review').animate({bottom:'0'}, 200);
            jQuery(this).find('.pro-view').show();
        });

</script>
```

But I am not finding how to fix second function.

```
, function(){  
        jQuery(this).find('.pro-review').stop(true,true).animate({bottom:'-37'}, 200);
        jQuery(this).find('.pro-view').hide();
    });
```

How to associate some thing like `.on("hover",".products-grid .item", function ()` for second function as I used for first function

Comment: Add another listener to `mouseleave`, that should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mouseleave` and `mouseenter` instead of `hover` with on.

```
jQuery(document).on("mouseleave",".products-grid .item", function () {
        jQuery(this).find('.pro-review').animate({bottom:'0'}, 200);
        jQuery(this).find('.pro-view').show();
});


jQuery(document).on("mouseenter",".products-grid .item", function () {
        jQuery(this).find('.pro-review').stop(true,true).animate({bottom:'-37'}, 200);
    jQuery(this).find('.pro-view').hide();
});
```

OR you can combine `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
         jQuery(this).find('.pro-review').animate({bottom:'0'}, 200);
         jQuery(this).find('.pro-view').show();
    },

    mouseleave: function () {
        jQuery(this).find('.pro-review').stop(true,true).animate({bottom:'-37'}, 200);
        jQuery(this).find('.pro-view').hide();
    }
}, '.products-grid .item');
```

Answer (score 2):

`'hover'` isn't actually its own event, but a [shorthand for 2 others](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

> Calling `$(selector).hover(handlerIn, handlerOut)` is shorthand for:
>
> ```
>  $(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);
> ```

For delegated binding, you can specify them directly:

```
jQuery(document).on({
    'mouseenter': function(){ 
        jQuery(this).find('.pro-review').animate({bottom:'0'}, 200);
        jQuery(this).find('.pro-view').show();
    },
    'mouseleave': function(){  
        jQuery(this).find('.pro-review').stop(true,true).animate({bottom:'-37'}, 200);
        jQuery(this).find('.pro-view').hide();
    }
}, '.products-grid .item');
```